# Ruby (on Rails) Regex: removing thousands comma from numbers

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

This seems like a simple one, but I am missing something.

I have a number of inputs coming in from a variety of sources and in different formats.

Number inputs

```
123
123.45
123,45 (note the comma used here to denote decimals)
1,234
1,234.56
12,345.67
12,345,67 (note the comma used here to denote decimals)
```

Additional info on the inputs

- Numbers will always be less than 1 million
- EDIT: These are prices, so will either be whole integers or go to the hundredths place

I am trying to write a regex and use gsub to strip out the thousands comma. How do I do this?

I wrote a regex: `myregex = /\d+(,)\d{3}/`

When I test it in Rubular, it shows that it captures the comma only in the test cases that I want.

But when I run gsub, I get an empty string: `inputstr.gsub(myregex,"")`

It looks like gsub is capturing everything, not just the comma in ().  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not possible if you have different sources. You can't differentiate whether `.` in `123.456` is thousand separator or decimal point. You need to extract the context before doing the removal.

Comment: @nhahtdh - my apologies, I edited to add that these are prices, which places some limit on the breadth of inputs.

Comment: `12,345,67` <-- Which country uses this one anyway?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
result = inputstr.gsub(/,(?=\d{3}\b)/, '')
```

removes commas only if exactly three digits follow.

`(?=...)` is a lookahead assertion: It needs to be possible to be matched at the current position, but it's not becoming part of the text that is actually matched (and subsequently replaced).

Comment: This was very helpful to me. I needed to implement it in R, so for anyone else needing to do the same, here is the R version: `gsub(",(?=\\d{3}\\b)", "", x, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: if you had the string "abc,123" you would match against this regular expression as well. Is there a reason to avoid specifying digits before the comma as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing "match" with "capture": to "capture" means to save something so you can refer to it later. You want to capture not the comma, but everything else, and then use the captured portions to build your substitution string.

Try

```
myregex = /(\d+),(\d{3})/

inputstr.gsub(myregex,'\1\2')
```

Comment: That will fail as soon as there is more than one comma to replace: `1,000,000.00` will become `1000,000.00`.

Comment: O.P. is aware - he wrote: "[numbers will always be less than 1 million]". So i was showing him how to make his regexp work, rather than creating a new one for him.

Comment: @theglauber - thanks for this. It's a good simple solution for this problem as well. I selected lookahead assertion one because it is likely to be more robust, e.g. more than 2 groupings are needed for some reason.

Comment: Oh yes, Tim Pietzkler's solution with the lookahead assertion is better. You should be able to generalize a solution with captures too ("there's more than one way to do it"). But i would pick that solution too.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it is **possible** to tell from the number of digits after the last separator (either `,` or `.`) that it is a decimal point, since there are 2 lone digits. For *most* cases, if the last group of digits does not have 3 digits then you can assume that the separator in front is decimal point. Another sign is the multiple appearance of a separator in big numbers allows us to differentiate between decimal point and separators.

However, I can give a string `123,456` or `123.456` without any sort of context. It is **impossible** to tell whether they are "123 thousand 456" or "123 point 456".

You need to scan the document to look for clue whether `,` is used for thousand separator or decimal point, and vice versa for `.`. With the context provided, then you can safely apply the same method to remove the thousand separators.

You may also want to check out [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) on Wikipedia on the less common ways to specify separators or decimal points. Knowing and deciding not to support is better than assuming things will work.

Comment: The data seems to be prices though. Prices will never have 3 decimals.

Comment: @pguardiario: The fact that is is price adds to the context so that one can make assumption about it. There is no way for me to guess that it is price.

Comment: Really? I had no problem guessing that :)

Comment: @nhahtdh - again apologies. See comment and edit above regarding prices.